pool.map() method of Python ThreadPoolExecutor can accept more iterables?
I would like to know if method pool.map of class ThreadPoolExecutor can accept more than one iterable.
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def increment(n1,n2):
    print(n1+1)
    print(n2+2)

def main():
    print("hello")
    list_numbers=[2,2,2]
    second_list=[3,3,3,3]
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as pool:
        pool.map(increment,list_numbers,second_list)


if __name__ ==  "__main__":
    main()

I tried this example that it worked, but I don't know if could be a problem with something else.
In this example, there is  just a print function that increments the list numbers of first_list and second_list.
Is this a good practice for threading, or it is not correct?
I know that the pool map function can accept only one iterable, but with two, it works.
I expected like a syntax error why it works?

for the doc it should works. Also possible signature pool.map(increment, *[list_numbers, second_list])

I’m voting to close this question because it can be answered by reading help(ThreadPoolExecutor.map). Notice further that print is not thread-safe
